# Oracle 12c missing GSMADMIN_INTERNAL

Tags: oracle

Oracle 12c 12.2.0.1

The GSMADMIN_INTERNAL user was erroneously deleted apparently some weeks ago. Datapump no longer works for export (ORA39006 and 390065) as well as ORA-00942 table or view does not exist. And ultimately ORA-39097 Data Pump job encountered unexpected error -942

So, I'm wondering is there any practical way to restore the GSMADMIN_INTERNAL user and its objects? I do not have RMAN backups going back that far. I do have datapump dumps from before the deletion, but I suspect impdp.exe will be just as broken as expdp.exe. Is there a way to manually create the user and its objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are scripts for removing and creating this, but they are not well-documented on their own.

I would just create a backup of the database then rerun the catalog scripts.

```
startup upgrade
@?/rdbms/admin/catalog.sql
@?/rdbms/admin/catproc.sql
@?/rdbms/admin/utlrp.sql
```

GSMADMIN_INTERNAL and related objects are created in other scripts called by catalog.sql.

The above may finish without any error, but you may need to take care of others errors encountered during or after this.

Comment: I tried this on test server and it appears to take care of the problem. I'll give it a shot in production. Thanks!